# Java stringbuffer method

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I am learning Java in this summer st college in US. I am new to Stringmethod.

I try to understand how to use `Stringbuffer()` method.

I tried to make  `ssl=statusBuffe`r in Else if section, but it causes error; how should I fix appropriate way?

Thank you so much.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s= "123-45-6789";
        String ssl;
        int slength = (s.length());

        if(slength ==11)
        {
            ssl = s;
        }
        else if(slength =9){
            StringBuffer statusBuffer = new StringBuffer(s);
            statusBuffer.insert(3,"-");
            statusBuffer.insert(6,"-");

            ssl=statusBuffer; //------ This part is causing error**
        }
        System.out.println(ssl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the JavaDoc of the `StringBuffer` _class_?

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand? Look at the `toString()` method.

Comment: The types are not compatible for assignment. You need to call toString() on the status buffer object.

Answer (score 1):

`ssl` is a String. `statusBuffer` is a StringBuffer.

You need
    ssl = statusBuffer.toString();

Answer (score 1):

StringBuffer is not a string. You have to call `statusBuffer.toString()` to actually get the String from your StringBuffer.

In Java, Strings cannot be modified. If you create a String, it is always that String. If you modify a String, a new string is created. A StringBuffer is basically a modifiable String, which can be used for performance reasons when assembling big texts. They are also Thread safe. For more information, see the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)